# Speeding up rendering multiple models - OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I am wanting some advice for drawing many objects within OpenGL. I currently have a Model class which contains all my data for drawing and also the render call.

In my program I currently have it set up to push_back multiple models into a std::vector and then loop through them to render, as follows:

```
std::vector<Model> all_models;
...
for(auto &single_model : all_models){
    the_shader.setMat4("model", single_model.model);
    single_model.draw(the_shader);
}
```

But when rendering this, the performance is bad, once reaching approximately above 300 models (only ~3500 triangles) of a simple primitive (cube) the program already starts to lag.

Because all of my models will be different in the final product, I **do not** want to use instancing, they are simply all the same now for debug purposes.

My render_data is in the format of:

```
{
    pos1x, pos1y, pos1z, norm1x, norm1y, norm1z,
    pos2x, ...
    ...
}
```

And my draw call is as follows:

```
void Model::draw(Shader shader)
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, render_data.size() * sizeof(float), render_data.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // pos
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);

    // norm
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, (unsigned int)render_data.size());
}
```

I have also added my model class below for a complete example.

```
class Model
{
public:
    Model(std::string inFilePath);
    ~Model();

    void draw(Shader shader);

    std::vector<unsigned int> vertIndices;
    std::vector<unsigned int> normIndices;

    std::vector<glm::vec3> vertices;
    std::vector<glm::vec3> normals;

    std::vector<float> render_data;

    // Model matrix
    glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);

    unsigned int VAO, VBO;
};
```

What ways could this code be improved to speed up the rendering of multiple (different) models?

Comment: You generate new VBOs/VAOs in every frame (and never delete them). Don't do that. Create them once during initialization, upload data only once and then just draw them in every frame. Only the last two lines of your draw method should stay in this method.

Comment: @BDL This has pretty much fixed all of the issues I had. Thank you for spotting this.